# How do I change the user agent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm having trouble with [`phantom`](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) the node wrapper around [`phantomjs`](http://phantomjs.org/).

This is how you do it in native phantomjs.

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the user agent string in the phantom module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567995/how-to-set-the-user-agent-string-in-the-phantom-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search found a [**thread on GitHub**](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom/issues/6) about this, looks like the you need to use `page.set`, e.g.

```
page.set('settings.userAgent', 'new useragent');
```

or when choosing multiple settings,

```
page.set('settings', {
    userAgent: 'new useragent',
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    loadImages: true
});
```